# HTML Table does not display MySQL data correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I run multiple MySQL queries and based on variables such as a person their function etc. it should output data into rows and columns in an HTML table. However, when the code is run, it ends up in one big mess, with the data not following the correct columns. See the image below for more information (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xCky.jpg). I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, as it seems to me that I have placed all the 'tr' and 'td' correctly.[image: This is how the HTML table ends up looking on the webpage]

```
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user1'])){
        header("location:".WEBROOT."index.php");
        exit();
    }
include_once DOCROOT . 'DBconnect.php';
    ?>

<html>
<head>
    <?php
    $title = "Participants";
    $file = __FILE__;
    include DOCROOT . 'pages/menu.php';
    ?>
<div id="content">
<div class="widecontentitem" id="lastitem">
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT institutionID FROM users WHERE users.UserID = \'' . $_SESSION['user1'] . '\'');
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    $institutionID = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $institutionID = $row[0];
    }
    print "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"institution\" value=\"" . $institutionID . "\"> ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT participants.name, participants.surname, participants.email, participants.special, participants.housingcomments, participants.functionID, participants.infix, participants.committee, participants.dateOfBirth, participants.housing, participants.countryID, participants.participantID FROM participants WHERE participants.institutionID =' . $institutionID);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query:2 ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    print "<table>";
    print "<tr><th><b>Function</b></th><th><b>Name</b></th><th><b>Surname</b></th><th><b>Date Of Birth</b></th><th><b>Country</b></th><th><b>Committee</b></th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
       if($row[9]==1){
          $row[0] = "(H)" . $row[0];
        }

        if( $row[5]==4){
            $title = "Delegate ";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT delegation FROM delegations WHERE ambassadorID =' . $row[11] );
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
            if($num_rows==1){
                $title = "Ambassador ";
            }
            $result2 = mysqli_query($db_link, 'SELECT delegation FROM delegations WHERE delegationID = ' . $row[10] );
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                print "<tr><td>$title </td><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1] </td><td>$row[8] </td><td>$row2[0] </td><td>$row[7]   </td></tr>";
            }
        }
        if( $row[5]==2){
            print "<tr><td>MUN-Director </td><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1] </td><td>$row[8] </td><td></td><td></td></tr>";
        }
        if($row[5]==5){
            print "<tr><td>President </td><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1] </td><td>$row[8] </td><td></td><td>$row[7] </td></tr>";
        }
        if($row[5]==6){
            print "<tr><td>Deputy President </td><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1] </td><td>$row[8] </td><td></td><td>$row[7]  </td></tr>";
        }
        if($row[5]==7){
            print "<tr><td>Chair </td><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1] </td><td>$row[8] </td><td></td><td>$row[7] </td></tr>";
        }
        if($row[5]==8){
            print "<tr><td>Deputy Chair </td><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1] </td><td>$row[8] </td><td></td><td>$row[7] </td></tr>";
        }
        if($row[4]!=NULL || $row[3]!=NULL){
            print "<table>";
            if($row[3]!=NULL){
                print "<tr><td colspan=\"6\">Comments: </td><td>$row[3] </td></tr>";
            }
            if($row[4]!=NULL){
                print "<tr><td colspan=\"6\">Housing: </td><td>$row[4] </td></tr>";
            }
            print "</table>";
        }
    }
    print "</table>";
    ?>
</div>
<?php include '../footer.php';?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is likely nested <table> elements from here:

```
if($row[4]!=NULL || $row[3]!=NULL){
            print "<table>";
            if($row[3]!=NULL){
```

From [MDN Table Element Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table):

> **Permitted content**      In this order:
>
> - an optional `<caption>` element,
> - zero or more `<colgroup>` elements,
> - an optional `<thead>` element,
> - either one of the following:
>
>   - zero or more `<tbody>` elements
>   - one or more `<tr>` elements
> - an optional `<tfoot>` element

You might want to use something like [Nu Html](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to validate the HTML. One way to use it is

- right-click the page and choose "View Page Source" or similar, depending on your browser
- select all and copy
- Choose Check by: `text input` in the validator
- paste the page source, and click check

Comment: Removing the extra <table> tags indeed solved my problem. Nu Html pointed this out to me too. Thanks for your help and the quick response!